# Converting a multi-level JSON menu to a multi-level JSX/HTML menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, smartmenus

I am using [SmartMenus](https://jsfiddle.net/vadikom/oxe40pat) to create a drop down menu. However, I am wanting to create the menu dynamically. The React app will query the API server for JSON code and a menu will be constructed out of that. I am trying to figure out a way to convert the JSON code to HTML/JSX code:

The JSON code retrieved from the API will look something like this:

```
{
        "module_type": "menu",
        "title": "My Site",
        "menu": [
                {
                        "link": "/home",
                        "title": "Home"
                },
                {
                        "link": "#",
                        "title": "Fruit",
                        "menu": [
                                {
                                        "link": "/apples",
                                        "title": "Apples"
                                },
                                {
                                        "link": "/bananas",
                                        "title": "Bananas"
                                },
                                {
                                        "link": "/kiwi",
                                        "title": "Kiwi"
                                },
                                {
                                        "link": "/pears",
                                        "title": "Pears"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "link": "#",
                        "title": "Vegetables",
                        "menu": [
                                {
                                        "link": "/carrots",
                                        "title": "Carrots"
                                },
                                {
                                        "link": "/celery",
                                        "title": "Celery"
                                },
                                {
                                        "link": "/potatoes",
                                        "title": "Potatoes"
                                },
                                {
                                        "link": "#",
                                        "title": "More",
                                        "menu": [
                                              {
                                                      "link": "/thirdlevel1",
                                                      "title": "3rd level menu"
                                              },
                                              {
                                                      "link": "/thirdlevel2",
                                                      "title": "3rd level two"
                                              }
                                        ]
                               }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "link": "/about",
                        "title": "About"
                },
                {
                        "link": "/contact",
                        "title": "Contact"
                }
        ]
}
```

Based on this JSON data, I would like to generate the following HTML/JSX code:

```
<nav className="main-nav" role="navigation">

  <input id="main-menu-state" type="checkbox" />
  <label className="main-menu-btn" htmlFor="main-menu-state">
    <span className="main-menu-btn-icon"></span> Toggle main menu visibility
  </label>

  <h2 className="nav-brand"><a href="#">My Site</a></h2>


  <ul id="main-menu" className="sm sm-blue">
    <li className="nav-item"><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
    <li><a href="#">No Fruit</a>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/apples">Apples</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/bananas">Bananas</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/kiwi">Kiwi</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/pears">Pears</Link></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Vegetables</a>
      <ul>
        <li className="nav-item"><Link to="/carrots">Carrots</Link></li>
        <li className="nav-item"><Link to="/celery">Celery</Link></li>
        <li className="nav-item"><Link to="/potatoes">Potatoes</Link></li>
        <li><a href="#">more...</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#>3rd level menu</a></li>
              <li><a href="#>3rd level two</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li className="nav-item"><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
    <li className="nav-item"><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The following link offers a solution: [Turning nested JSON into an HTML nested list with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211764/turning-nested-json-into-an-html-nested-list-with-javascript) . However, this does not seem to work well with JSX as you cannot use document.createElement() with React/JSX elements.

Given that I am using multiple levels of menus, what is an efficient way to do this in React with a mix of JSX and html elements?

Comment: Do a search for *"recursive tree component"*

Comment: @charlietfl One problem that I am encountering is JSX does not allow me to add child elements.

Comment: This is what I am referring to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028198/add-children-to-react-element

Comment: @kojow7 can you please check my implementation? Also if you have any further questions - feel free to write me a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a dynamically generated menu, using JSX and your sample data.

As you can see, we're recursively iterating over your menu items while building the JSX:

```js
const renderMenu = items => {
  return <ul>
    { items.map(i => {
      return <li>
        <a href={i.link}>{ i.title }</a>
        { i.menu && renderMenu(i.menu) }
      </li>
    })}
  </ul>
}

const Menu = ({ data }) => {
  return <nav>
    <h2>{ data.title }</h2>
    { renderMenu(data.menu) }
  </nav>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Menu data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // The sample data is declared here, only to keep the React example short and clear
  const data = {
    "module_type": "menu",
    "title": "My Site",
    "menu": [{
        "link": "/home",
        "title": "Home"
      },
      {
        "link": "#",
        "title": "Fruit",
        "menu": [{
            "link": "/apples",
            "title": "Apples"
          },
          {
            "link": "/bananas",
            "title": "Bananas"
          },
          {
            "link": "/kiwi",
            "title": "Kiwi"
          },
          {
            "link": "/pears",
            "title": "Pears"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "link": "#",
        "title": "Vegetables",
        "menu": [{
            "link": "/carrots",
            "title": "Carrots"
          },
          {
            "link": "/celery",
            "title": "Celery"
          },
          {
            "link": "/potatoes",
            "title": "Potatoes"
          },
          {
            "link": "#",
            "title": "More",
            "menu": [{
                "link": "/thirdlevel1",
                "title": "3rd level menu"
              },
              {
                "link": "/thirdlevel2",
                "title": "3rd level two"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "link": "/about",
        "title": "About"
      },
      {
        "link": "/contact",
        "title": "Contact"
      }
    ]
  }
</script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Jordan, thanks for checking back. I think it's mostly working for me. There's still a couple of things I'm still trying to fix up though. For example, removing the `div` around the h2 and menu. And having both `Link` and `a` tags (I got this working now). Also, for some reason the menu interaction is slower, so not sure why that it is. I'll likely have to post another question about that aspect once I get this one working the menu structured the way I like it.

Comment: @kojow7, I replaced the `<div />` with `<nav />` element. As you can see you can easily change whatever you want in the generated structure with my code example. Also my answer provides clear way for generating JSX from nested JSON, so if helped you - you can accept and award it. Thanks. About the interaction - you can post another question, because here the focus is onto generating JSX from JSON.